# seria buena practica usar el do de esta manera?

Tags: java

Tengo una duda con el while y el do realmente no tengo muy claro su uso

```
 int i = 0;
    do{
      System.out.println("Hola");
    }while(i<5);
```

Pregunto porque para los ciclo suelo utilizar el for y foreach

Comment: Así tal cual está en tu pregunta, creo que no sería buena idea. Es un ciclo infinito porque siempre i<5

Comment: Eso depende, qué es lo que planteas lograr imprimir?

Comment: @Pak Lei Chong solo le haría falta el incremento ++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andres. Tu pregunta es referente a aclarar un poco las diferentes aplicaciones del while respecto del for (o eso entiendo cuando leo tu pregunta). Es decir ¿Cuándo nos conviene o tenemos que usar un for y cuándo un while?

Uno de los requerimientos o limitantes principales para elegir un **while** es que no conocemos el momento exacto en que la condición de paro se cumplirá ... pueden pasar 3 iteraciones, 200, tal vez 1000 y el programa podría seguir en ejecución. En cambio con un **for** o un **foreach** generalmente se itera sobre un arreglo y para cada ciclo se valoran ciertas condiciones, por ejemplo, que un contador no sea mayor a la longitud del arreglo.

Según respuestas de la misma comunidad de Stack Overflow en inglés existen diferencias entre el rendimiento de un **while** y el de un **do-while**. Pero para la mayoría de las computadoras/servidores actuales con una aplicación pequeña no debería de ser un problema.

Ahora, Un ejemplo de un ordenamiento burbuja en Java es el siguiente:

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){  
                 for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
                          if(arr[j-1] > arr[j]){  
                                 //swap elements  
                                 temp = arr[j-1];  
                                 arr[j-1] = arr[j];  
                                 arr[j] = temp;  
                         }  
                          
                 }  
         }
```

Como puedes ver, para poder ejecutar un ordenamiento de burbuja sobre un arreglo con un par de fors **es necesario conocer de antemano la longitud** del arreglo. Ahora, también es importante mencionar que es posible hacer el ordenamiento con un while, pero tal vez por comodidad o algunas veces por costumbre preferimos el utilizar el for.

Ahora, imagina que eres un desarrollador de un videojuego y tu personaje necesita comer de vez en cuando ... pero no sabes **cuándo** le va a dar hambre ... Puede ser que pasen horas y todo esté en calma o pueden pasar 3 minutos y ya apareció el mounstro más desgraciado de todo el juego y para poder derrotarlo necesitarás algo más que palabras dulces, lo que es seguro es que nadie queda bien librado después de una pelea épica y lo menos que pide un personaje será comer:

```
do { 
  comer();
 } while (hambriento());

private void comer(){
  this.energia += 5;
}

private boolean hambriento(){
  return this.energia<100 ? true : false;
}
```

En los videojuegos se le llama a este ciclo infinito el [ciclo del juego](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2167437&seqNum=2) y es un pseudo-patrón muy común. Espero que con esto te quede más clara la diferencia y los posibles usos de ambos casos. Sobre tu pregunta de qué falta para terminar tu código, sí, sólo el incremento me parece, como Youshiro te comenta.

Answer (score 2):

El **while** solo se ejecuta cuando una condición se cumple, y mientras se este cumpliendo se volverá a ejecutar. A diferencia el **do while**, el código que este dentro del `do` se ejecutara al menos una vez en el código, y si la condición del `while` se cumple, volverá a repetirse el código dentro del `do`. Y en tu caso, es un bucle infinito por que `i` siempre vale 0.

Para que tu código deje de estar en bucle infinito debes de hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
 int i = 0;
    do{
      System.out.println("Hola");
      i++;
    }while(i<5);
```

Debes, a cada vuelta del ciclo, incrementar la variable `i` para que en el momento sea igual a 5, el bucle deje de repetirse.

Y otro método que puedes utilizar seria este:

```
 int i = 0;
    while(i<5){
      System.out.println("Hola");
      i++;
    };
```

Y en este caso, solo aparecera el mensaje de **Hola** si la `i` es menor que 5, que en este caso, lo es.