# ¿Que diferencia hay entre dormir el ciclo principal y el uso de timer en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, hilos

Estoy realizando un pequeño juego de snake en Java y he visto que muchas personas usan un timer para hacer el movimiento del snake, y me ha surgido la duda de que es lo que hace el timer exactamente?
Hay alguna diferencia entre hacer un timer y hacer un while true con Thread.sleep(100)?

Comment: El ciclo que mencionas tiene su nombre en la literatura de desarrolladores de videojuegos y se le conoce como game loop o main game loop y al respecto puedes revisar mis respuestas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/272749/342 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/330872/342

Comment: Si duermes el hilo principal no podrás realizar actualizaciones en la interface durante el tiempo que este dormido o encerrado en el while, mientras que timer al ser un hilo aparte no afectará el proceso principal de dibujado se la interfaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) permite correr funciones en un hilo aparte, con lo cual toda tu interfaz mantendrá su funcionalidad constantemente.

Por otro lado, si usas un `while(true)` y dentro metes un `thread.sleep(100)` tu aplicación quedará "colgada" durante esos 100ms en cada iteración del while.

En el caso que planteas no veo gran diferencia **a no ser que vayas a tener un servicio de fondo intentando acceder a recursos que estén en uso en el hilo principal**, pues el principal problema de usar `Thread.sleep()` es que bloqueamos el acceso a todos los recursos que estén abiertos por el hilo que pausas, por ejemplo, si tienes un archivo abierto (para leer o guardar la puntuación) y un servicio intenta abrir ese mismo archivo para actualizarlo dará fallo, pues el archivo está bloqueado por el hilo principal, el cual se queda "congelado" todo el rato.

Comment: O sea, si uso el while true con ```Thread.sleep()``` no podría hacer nada estilo captar un Event del teclado no?

Comment: Si capturas el evento en el mismo hilo que pones a dormir, es posible que eso suceda si. Por eso por lo general la interfaz se debe ejecutar en un hilo específico para ella siempre, así nunca pierdes inputs ni el programa se queda irresponsivo.